# How to paginate mongoTemplate query in springBoot?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mongotemplate

This is my method in which I am using mongoTemplate , now my requirement is to paginate it but even though I am using following it is not getting paginated , I simply want to return 10 records but I am getting all , can someone pls help me with it .. ,

```
       Query query = new Query().with(pageable);
    MongoCursor<String> cursor = mongoTemplate.getCollection(collection).distinct(fieldName, query.getQueryObject(), String.class).iterator();
    long count = mongoTemplate.getCollection(collection).countDocuments(query.getQueryObject());
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        list.add(cursor.next());
    }
    return PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(list, pageable, () -> count);

}
```